# How to get min value from array in F#?

Tags: f#

This is F# code as close as I can write to find the min value of an array:

```
let temp = 0
let getArrayMinValue (a : Array) = 
    if a.Length > 0 then (
                            for i = 0 to a.Length do
                               let temp =  ( if temp > a.[i] then a.[i] else temp )  in ()                       
                        )
```

I have two questions:
First, **a.[i]** has compiling error: *The field, constructor or member 'Item' is not defined.*

Second, the *in ()* is requried, otherwise, there is compiling error "Block following this let is unfinished. Expect an expression". I do not quite understand this part.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can't you use [Array.min](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370460.aspx) to find the minimum element, something like below:

```
let numbers =[|1..10|]

printfn "%A"  (numbers |> Array.min)
```

Coming to you program, you have to use something like:

```
let getArrayMinValue (a : int[]) =
```

and not `a: Array` You can even do `a: 'T[]` but since you are comparig the value of the elements against temp it will probably constraint it to int.

Coming to the other error, make temp mutable: `let mutable temp = 0` and assign value using `<-` operator. Here is your whole code:

```
let mutable temp = 0


let getArrayMinValue (a : 'T[]) = 
   if a.Length > 0 then (
                        for i = 0 to a.Length do
                           temp <-  ( if temp > a.[i] then a.[i] else temp )
                        )
```